# Expo + React Native: OTA update when upgrading Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I currently have a live react native + expo app on the app store. I have successfully made OTA updates in the past for updates in my JS code and seen my app update automatically.

Locally, I have successfully updated the app from Expo v35 to v36 using these instructions: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-36-is-now-available-b91897b437fe

My question is, is it safe for me to make an OTA update now? I did notice that I had to fix a few things in my JS code to work with v36 (specifically changing `CameraRoll` to `MediaLibrary`). Just trying to make sure I don't break the app for all my existing users.

Comment: What prevent you and what make you feel that it isn't safe anymore to do OTA update?

Comment: Because I'm not sure if there's anything under the hood that is more than just the superficial JS changes that I usually make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OTA updates you published on v36 will not be pushed to users still on v35.
i.e. they will remain on the last OTA update you published while on v35.

Hence, it should be safe to publish updates you made to v36 as only users on v36 will receive them.

Users on v35 can only upgrade to v36 via the Google Play / App Store as Expo SDK upgrades involve native code changes that cannot be delivered through OTA updates.